# Question Mark or Not With Continuation of Question?

Tags: question-mark

Should there be a question mark after "in the story"?
I know it's not a direct question, but it is a continuation of the original question & requires an answer

> Tim: So what happened next?
>   Mum: What do you mean?
>   Tim: In the story?

Comment: It could be argued that he is asking 'what happened next in the story?' in which case the question mark would be ok and would also indicate a question intonation.

Comment: @SConroy I disagree: he's *clarifying* his earlier question, but *not actually asking* a question.

Comment: @Trevor D. I think if it was part of a short story or a literary piece, the presence or absence of the question mark would make a difference to how the reader 'hears' the dialogue. In my view it's a matter of context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. It is a separate statement. If it were together, then yes.

> *So what happened next in the story?*

As a response to *"What do you mean"*, it is a statement.

> *I mean, "in the story." What happened next in the story?*